# Retrieving Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner at sql. I am trying to retrieve the following data:

- tutor.tutorData.TutorLastName
- tutor.sessionData.StudentKey
- tutor.sessionData.SessionDateKey
- tutor.sessionData.SessionTimeKey
- tutor.sessionData.CourseKey

Here's my code:

```
    SELECT t.TutorLastName
    ,s.StudentKey
    ,s.SessionDateKey
    ,s.SessionTimeKey
    ,s.CourseKey
FROM `tutor`.`tutorData` t
    ,`tutor`.`sessionData` s
INNER JOIN `tutor`.`sessionData` s ON t.TutorKey = s.TutorKey;
```

Error Code:

> 1066. Not unique table/alias: 's'.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e93131/1

remove `, tutor. sessionData s`

```
SELECT t.TutorLastName, s.StudentKey, s.SessionDateKey, s.SessionTimeKey, s.CourseKey
FROM `tutor`.`tutorData` t
INNER JOIN `tutor`.`sessionData` s 
ON t.TutorKey = s.TutorKey;
```

Comment: yeah but that only return TutorLastName. I also want to get StudentKey, SessionDateKey, SessionTimeKey, CourseKey from sessionData s

Comment: Thank you for your help!